# Getting the CLOSED timestamp of the current subtree

Tags: org-mode

To get the current date and time, I can use `(current-time)`.

But instead, I want to get the CLOSED timestamp of the current subtree and store it in a variable, so that I can pass it to `format-time-string`.

What's the simplest function to retrieve the CLOSED timestamp of a subtree?

Answer (score 1):

```el
;; in some hook or something:

(let ((timestamp (assoc "CLOSED" (org-entry-properties))))
  (when timestamp
    ;; couder is timestamp's value
    (princ (cdr timestamp))))
```